# Will git permanently remove files from index and history if the files were added and removed within a rebase with squash?

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

on develop branch someone added a directory they shouldn't have to our repo, and I have since removed the files.  Now, if I go back and do a rebase and squash the commits from prior to the add to after the add, will it be like the files were never added to the repo, or will they still be in the index or history somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index is never permanent.  It's largely a *temporary* data structure that Git uses to build the *next* commit you make.  You can alter it any time you like using `git add` or `git rm`; and `git checkout` and similar commands fill it from commits.  So this part of the question:

> will [files] still be in the index

is not really a sensible question.

The other part, though, is more useful:

> will [files] still be in ... history somewhere?

History in Git *is* commits; commits *are* history.

No commit can ever be changed, but you can get Git to *forget* commits.  Git finds commits by starting from branch names, tag names, and other such references: each reference holds exactly one hash ID, of some underlying Git object—mostly commit objects and occasionally tag objects, for annotated tags.  Tag objects hold another hash ID, usually that of a commit; commit objects hold additional commit hash IDs, which identify their predecessor commits.

Hence, "history" consists of starting from a name like `master`, which contains a hash ID: some big ugly string of letters and digits, but let's just call it `H`:

```
        ... <-H   <-- master
```

Commit `H` itself contains another big ugly hash ID; let's call it `G`:

```
     ... <-G <-H   <-- master
```

Commit `G` itself contains another big ugly hash ID.  Let's call this one `F`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
```

and so on, and on.  That's history!

To find the history in a *repository*, we just start at all the ending points and work backwards:

```
        D--E   <-- dev
       /
A--B--C
       \
        F--G--H   <-- master
```

Commit `A` is the very first one, so it doesn't connect to anything earlier.  Commits `A-B-C` are on *both* branches.  Commit `E` is the end of `dev`, commit `H` is the end of `master`.  By starting at `E` and working backwards we visit five commits.  By starting at `H` and working backwards, we visit six, three of them the same as ones we visit from `dev`.  So there are eight total commits: three shared, two unique to `dev`, and three unique to `master`.

What `git rebase` does is to *copy* (some) commits to new and improved ones.  Let's say we rebase `dev` to have just *one* unique, but new-and-improved, commit.  Let's call that one commit `I`.  We just arrange for `I`'s predecessor—the hash ID in commit `I` that lets us / Git go backwards—to be that of commit `C`:

```
        D--E   [abandoned]
       /
A--B--C--I   <-- dev
       \
        F--G--H   <-- master
```

Now there are four total commits on `dev`.

Commits `D` and `E` *still exist*.  We cannot *change* them!  But we cannot *find* them either, because we find commits by starting from all the *names* and working backwards.  No names lead us to `E`; no names lead us to `D`.

Git keeps some additional, hidden, log entries—in what Git calls *reflogs*—around for a while in case our rebase was a mistake.  While those additional reflog entries exist, we can use `git reflog dev` or `git reflog HEAD` to find the hash ID of commit `E`, and probably directly that of `D` as well.  So the reflogs keep the commits alive.

Reflog entries eventually expire.  Once expired, they get deleted.  Once deleted, they no longer protect commits.  Once *all* protection is gone, the commits—and their associated snapshots—become eligible for *garbage collection*, or GC.  The default for reflog entry expiration is both 30 days and 90 days: 90 days is the time for a *reachable* entry, and 30 days for an *unreachable* entry, with the definition of *reachable* being based on the current hash ID stored in the reference by which this particular reflog exists.  In your case, having rebased `dev` to collapse all the old commits down to one new-and-improved replacement, the old ones are considered unreachable, and hence get 30 days.

Because Git is always creating *new* objects, some of which eventually get referenced and stick around, any object that's not at least 14 days old by default is spared from the garbage collector.  The garbage collector also doesn't run all the time: Git runs `git gc --auto` to *automatically* invoke it whenever it looks like a GC would be profitable.

Since 30 days is more than 14 days, your old commits will be collected some time after 30 days after the rebase.  To make it happen sooner, you can manually expire the reflogs right away, and manually run a subsequent `git gc`.  But mostly you should just let Git do it.

Comment: excellent answer, thank you for the details of what's going on